# Images and branching in Sharepoint Survey 2013

Tags: survey

We have added an image to our survey as well as branched the 1st question.  The issue is when you click on Respond to this Survey, you immediately see Q1, but directly under it you see the image.  The image should not be seen until the very last question.  If you uncheck the default answer in Q1, then click on Next, it takes you to the rest of the survey, but then you never see the image in the last question.  How do we fix this?